# Filling out array with function in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm now using numpy for my assignment and I come across this problem.

So I have a function with 3 inputs which goes like this:

```
import numpy as np
def calculate_boundary_temperature(A,w,t):
    T_boundary = A*np.sin(w*t)
```

Then I want to create an array that contains the output of this function for A=50 and w=pi/20 and t=0 to t=400, interval = 1. So I tried a code like this:

```
A = 50
w = np.pi/20
t = np.arange(0,400,1)
T = calculate_boundary_temperature (A,w,t)
print ("T:{}".format(T))
```

Then I expected an array with 400 inputs in it but the actual output is like this:

```
T: None
```

So I would like to ask how should I code to get the list I wanted? I'm not familiar with programming so I'm sorry if that's actually a simple mistake. Thanks in advance for all your assistance.

Comment: A function without `return` returns `None`.  Unfortunately to use `numpy` you have to know something, at least, about the language it's written in - python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the value from the function. Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
def calculate_boundary_temperature(A,w,t):
    T_boundary = A*np.sin(w*t)
    return T_boundary
```

Comment: Yes it is. Now I got the array I wanted. Thank you!